# Programmatically download html page - Objective C/Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a button called "Download page" at the bottom of my `detailView` of `SplitView` app in iPad. I want to download the corresponding html page on the click of the aforementioned button i.e. I need to add the functionality of the "Ctrl+S" for that button so that I could download and save the page. How can I do that ?

Comment: okay .. I can do that .. but I think my question just pertains as to saving the file in ios. where the file is in html format. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

```
//Download data from URL
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourstringURL"]];
//use this data to write to any path as documentdirectory path + filename.html
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//create file path
NSString *htmlFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.html"];
//write at file path
BOOL isSucess = [data writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES];
if (isSucess)
    NSLog(@"written");
else
    NSLog(@"not written");
```

You can same `htmlFilePath` to retrieve `html` file from `document directory`

Comment: what would the path for saving of the file be ?? I mean I am running the IPad simulator .. how can I know the path as to where I should save my file ??

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the html content inside an NSString and then save it, like so

```
NSString *allHtml = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
[allHtml writeToFile:@"YourFilePath" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

This will save all the HTML to the path you define

Comment: Thanks Omar.a And if I need to upload the same html file using another button called "Upload html", how would I do it ?? I mean what is the corresponding function ??

Comment: @zyxwvu you will need to start a request (asynch or synch) and send it to the webservice you want, this will need a new question since uploading is alittle harder, also dont forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if this was useful :)

Comment: what would the path for saving of the file be ?? I mean I am running the IPad simulator .. how can I know the path as to where I should save my file ??

Comment: @zyxwvu use this     NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/yourFile.txt"];